# How to call a function from a module name that is assigned to a variable

Tags: python, function, module

I am trying to call a function from a module. The module and the function have the same name, which is read at runtime using `raw_input()` and stored in a variable.

For example,

#### module.py

```
def module():
    print "x"
```

#### run.py

```
ent="module"
__import__(ent)
ent()
```

I can import that module using the variable `ent`. But when I call that function using that variable I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I call that function from the module when I don't know their name until runtime?

Comment: `ent` is still `"module"`, you haven't actually *assigned* the import. Also note that you would need to call `ent.module()`.

Comment: why not just `import module`?

Comment: This is do-able, but _why_ do you want the module and function names to be dynamic like that?

Comment: I found the question itself clear enough; hopefully my edit has made it a little clearer. I will admit that I'm still puzzled as to _why_ the OP wants to get the function & module name at runtime, perhaps it's an XY problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon mentioned, you didn't save a reference to the imported module. You need that to call its functions. To actually get to the function you can use the built-in `getattr` function. Eg,

```
ent = "module"
mod = __import__(ent)
func = getattr(mod, ent)
func()
```

However, using `__import__` is rather unusual, and only done in special situations. Is your situation special enough to warrant its use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.In the code ent is just a raw_input.And according to the raw_input it is importing that module which has the same name as the ent.And in that module there is a function which has the same name as the raw_input.So I have to import that module using that variable.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I will give it a try.